# MassTransit Sending Raw Json to an existing SQS Queue

Tags: amazon-sqs, masstransit

I have need to send raw json to an existing Sqs queue.

The queue url is https://sqs.region.amazonaws.com/accountid/mt-send-test.fifo.

I've done this configuration in Startup

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("mt-send-test.fifo", e =>
{
   e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
   e.ClearSerialization();
   e.UseRawJsonSerializer(isDefault: true);
});
```

At the point where I send the message, I can't seem to get the URI correct:

```
MyMessage mtMessage;
var endpoint = await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:mt-send-test.fifo"));
await endpoint.Send(mtMessage);
```

What is the correct way to do this?  If I try to use the whole url, I get an exception from GetSendEndpoint, but as it is, it doesn't seem to resolve the proper url.

I also get an exception trying to send my message object,
"Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSException: 'The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId.'"

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to configure the bus itself for raw JSON, since in the previous question you only configured the receive endpoint.

```cs
cfg.UseRawJsonSerializer(isDefault: true);
```

Then, once you get the endpoint provider, you need to specify the MessageGroupId:

```cs
var endpoint = await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:mt-send-test.fifo"));

await endpoint.Send(mTMessage, x => x.SetGroupId(x.Message.CorrelationId.ToString()));
```

You should *never* configure a receive endpoint without a consumer. This will result in an endpoint that simply moves every message retrieved to the *_skipped* queue.

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  That helped and I have it working.  In my case, I had to do the following,  as my queues also needed a de-dupe id:
```
await endpoint.Send(mtMessage, x =>
        {
            x.SetGroupId(...);
            x.SetDeduplicationId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        });
```
I'd been trying to use the same bus through-out, but from your answer, I looked into Multi-bus, so I've used a separate bus now, configured just for the bits that touch the external system.